# Missing 'wintrust.dll' file

Tags: laptop, internet-connection

I have a problem with my internet and I don't know what to do.
When I start Google Chrome or any other browser, it says that 'witrust.dll' file is missing.
I was told that it don't work because I'm missing a file called 'wintrust.dll',
so I looked for it and found three times the same 'wintrust.dll' file.
Could the problem be that I have it three times?

Answer (score 3):

The file wintrust.dll is a Windows DLL. To fix missing or currupted files, open the [cmd.exe as admin](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/How-do-I-run-an-application-once-with-a-full-administrator-access-token) and run [sfc](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929833) to fix the issue:

```
sfc /scannow
```